# what is difference between useNavigate and redirect in react-route v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was trying to build my authentication logic with react-router v6 in react
and I found some odd thing when I ran my code below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import useStore from '../../../store/store';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useNavigate,redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function (SpecificComponent, option, adminRoute = null) {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {auth,accessToken}= useStore();
// option = null // pages taht anyone can access
// option = true // pages that only loginuser can access
// option = false // pages that loginuser can not access
// option = true ,adiminRoute = true // pages that only admin can access
function AuthenticationCheck(props){

    useEffect(()=>{
        auth(accessToken).then(res => {
            
            if (res.accessToken) {
             
            setAccessToken(res.accessToken)
             
            }
        //when authentication failed
        if (res.isAuth===false) {
            if (option) {
                //to sign in page
                navigate('/signin')
            }
            //when authentication successed
        } else { 
            //trying to get in admin page but user is not admin 
            if (adminRoute && res.role !== "Admin") {
                navigate('/landingpage')
                //trying to get in admin page and user is  admin  
            } else if (adminRoute && res.role === "Admin") {
                navigate('/admin')
            } else { 
                //trying to get in login page but user is signed in already
                if (option === false) {navigate('/landing')}
                
            }

        }
        //passed above, go to SpecificComponent
    });

},[])
return(
    <SpecificComponent {...props}  />
 )
  }


  return AuthenticationCheck
}
```

when I ran this code and trying to get in admin page as admin user, I could get in admin page but It trapped in loop and rerender admin page over and over.

```
else if (adminRoute && res.role === "Admin") {
            navigate('/admin')
        }
```

so I changed navigate with another react-router method redirect and It worked totally fine.
However,I still couldn't get that why navigate dind't work but redirect did?

this is redirect

```
        export declare const redirect: RedirectFunction;
/**
 * @private
 * Utility class we use to hold auto-unwrapped 4xx/5xx Response bodies
 */
```

and this is useNavigate

```
    export declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
/**
 * Returns the context (if provided) for the child route at this level of the route
 * hierarchy.
 * @see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-outlet-context
 */
```

P.S Now, I get It It would've gone to admin page even I did my code like below but still not sure why useNavigate fall in infinity loop and that's what I want to know

```
else if (adminRoute && res.role === "Admin") {
                    
                }
```

Thx for reading, your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

From my understanding and reading from the docs, `redirect` is used in actions and loaders.

And `useNavigate` is a hook and it can only be used in React Hooks and React Components.

So for example you can use `useNavigate` to redirect the user in your Homepage Component, for example in some state change.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Homepage = () => {
  const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldRedirect) navigate("/profile");
  }, [shouldRedirect]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShouldRedirect(true)}>Redirect</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And redirect should be used in normal functions, like loaders and actions, citing an [example from the docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect#redirect):

```
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const loader = async () => {
  const user = await getUser();
  if (!user) {
    return redirect("/login");
  }
};
```

Source:

- [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)
- [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)

Comment: A simple thing worth pointing out if you're not familiar with React Router v6: "[loaders](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader) and [actions](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action)" are features of Data Routers, which you can learn about in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#data-loading). I found these terms late in my dev cycle on useNavigate's doc page, where it merely says "It's usually better to use redirect in loaders and actions than [useNavigate]." Trying to figure _why_ redirect is better led me here, yet no one points this out for noobs.

Answer (score 5):

1. The main difference between `useNavigate` and `redirect` is that `useNavigate` is a hook that returns a function, while `redirect` is a function that returns a response object.
2. If you use `navigate` in the `useEffect` hook, it will cause the browser to load the page, and the `useEffect` hook's setup function will run again, that's the loop introduced here. But `redirect` returns a `response`, in which case the `useEffect` hook does not work. In other words, `redirect` is a data rather than a behavior.
3. that's why the official document put `redirect` under category Fetch Utilities.